# Cross-Platform Bonjour

Tags: java, python, cross-platform, bonjour

Is it possible to write a program using Bonjour or a Bonjour-compatible library in a cross-platform language such as Java or Python?
If so, where can I find the files needed for this?

Comment: I think zeroconf is the term you're looking for. Unfortunately, I don't know any more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java have a look at the jmdns library which does it all in pure Java.  http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/

I do not believe it can delegate to the native implementation if running on OS X, but it has been a while, so it might these days.

Comment: This library appears to work well; however, I have not done very much with it so far.  JmDNS has not been updated since 2008, but the current version appears to workas well as I could ask for.